# I'm trying to do "blackbox testing" but keep getting a 404 error

Tags: github, server, restful-authentication

I set up ther server, but It does not connect to the test client. Here is my server: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lNmeiDbI4KfRwzfJJ3z8SQjN7WdQjrS3wZD3KvjJJMo/edit?usp=sharing. I just don't know what to do. I'm utterly lost. I have no knowledge of how to do blackbox testing or what to do with the test clients I was given for the assignment.